# Drop down list to create an order, cannot select the same number in each drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications

Good Day everyone,

Currently working on an application, inside the settings I have a list of drop down list that my clients can select. Those drop down list are to create an order in which they want those options to appear.

How can you make it, that they cannot select 2 times the same number, and if they do the "new" selection will go replace the "same number" with the old selection.

```
<select name="temporary-1">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select name="temporary-2">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select name="temporary-3">
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

I am currently using jQuery in my application, so what I was thinking is to compare each Drop Down on change, and if the same number exist already I would just switch both numbers.

Would it be a proper way? Or is there ways already to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers,

But those were not what I was looking for.

Here is how I did it:

First of, I already had a hidden field used for another purpose (which I forget to mention here).

```
$('.select_class').change(function () {
    var $currentselect = $(this);
    var $currentorder = $('input[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + '_current' + ']');
    $("select[name^='select_order_']").each(function () {
        var $checkcurrent = $('input[name=' + $(this).attr('name') + '_current' + ']');
        if (!$(this).is(':disabled')) {
            if($(this).prop('name') != $currentselect.prop('name')){
                if($(this).val() == $currentselect.val()){
                    $(this).val($currentorder.val())
                    $checkcurrent.val($currentorder.val())
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $currentorder.val($(this).val())
});
```

The $currentselect takes the field that was modified and keeps it as a variable to be used in the below sections

The $currentorder take the name of the .class_select and add _current (which becomes the hidden field with the current data.

For all the "select_order" I do the following checks:

1. Create the checkcurrent variable to modify it later if it is needed
2. Is it disabled, If it is just skip it
3. does the $currentselect value has the same value has the "select_order"
4. If it has the same value, change the current "select_order" with the $currentorder value and then allow the change to the $currentselect
5. change checkcurrent with the new value so the _current has the proper number for each

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the selectize.js library to implement your drop downs, it's located here: https://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that replaces the options with only ones that haven't been chosen in the other elements

```
var $selects = $('select.temp'),// added a common class to the elements
    opts = $selects.first().html()

$selects.change(function(){ 
    $selects.each(function(){
        var otherValues = $selects.not(this).map(function(){       
            return this.value ? this.value : null;      
         }).get();          
        var currVal = this.value;
        $(this).html(function(){
            return $(opts).filter(function(){
                return $.inArray(this.value, otherValues) === -1;
            });
        }).val(currVal);            
    });    
});
```

Also requires having an option with no value in each

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/evfx0sap/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a similar idea to `charlietfl`'s solution, but I went a little bit of a different route . . . my code disables any options that have already been selected in a different dropdown.  Like his, mine also requires that you have an option with no value (there are ways to avoid that, if needed, but, if you can add in a default like that, it makes the code much more simple).

**HTML**

```
<select name="temporary-1">
     <option value="">-</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select name="temporary-2">
     <option value="">-</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select name="temporary-3">
     <option value="">-</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $("select").on("change", disableOptions);
});

function disableOptions() {
    var $allSelectInputs = $("select");
    var sChangedSelectName = $(this).attr("name");
    var $changedSelectOptions = $(this).find("option");
    var sChangedSelectVal = $changedSelectOptions.filter(":selected").val();

    for (i = 0; i < $changedSelectOptions.length; i++) {
        if (!($($changedSelectOptions[i]).prop("disabled"))) {
            for (j = 0; j < $allSelectInputs.length; j++) {
                if ($($allSelectInputs[j]).attr("name") !== sChangedSelectName) {
                    var $currentSelectOption = $($($allSelectInputs[j]).find("option")[i]);
                    if (sChangedSelectVal !== "") {
                        if ($currentSelectOption.val() === sChangedSelectVal) {
                            $currentSelectOption.prop("disabled", true);
                        }
                        else {
                            $currentSelectOption.prop("disabled", false);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When an option is selected in one of the dropdowns, it will go through the other two and disable the value that matches the selection.  By disabling them, instead of removing them, you can easily "reinstate" the optoins, if a new selection is made.

Ideally, you would be able to hide the options, instead of disabling them, but there are browser support issues when it comes to applying `display: none;` to `<option>` tags (glares at IE).